# Cos'è una "parola di senso compiuto"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La giostra degli scambi* di Andrea Camilleri ho letto queste parole pronunciate dal commissario Montalbano:

> «Ora mi ascolti attentamente. Pare che lei, mentre veniva sollevata da terra dalla coppia per essere trasportata in casa, abbia detto una **parola di senso compiuto**».

Non capisco il senso dell'espressione "parola di senso compiuto" nella frase precedente. Ho cercato il significato di "compiuto" e di "compiere" alcuni dizionari, ma continuo a non capire. Potreste spiegarmelo?

**Aggiornamento:** 
Per si può essere utile, voglio precisare che precedentemente nel romanzo si spiega che la ragazza, che era stata sequestrata, venne trovata in stato confusionale. Ecco il dialogo in cui si parla di questo fatto:

> «Senta, sono sceso per andare nel garage a prendere l’auto e ho trovato per terra, davanti alla saracinesca, una donna completamente nuda e tutta coperta di sangue che si lamentava». «Ha detto come si chiama?». «Ma non parla! Si lamenta soltanto. Credo sia in stato confusionale. Mia moglie l’ha portata in casa».

Poi la coppia che aveva raccolto da terra questa ragazza ha avuto il dubbio se questa "parola di senso compiuto" fosse "auto" oppure "aiuto".

Comment: Normalmente è *frase di senso compiuto*, cioè che esprime qualcosa. Forse l'autore adopera *di senso compiuto* invece di *intellegibile*.

Comment: @egreg: Infatti la coppia che raccoglie da terra la ragazza a cui fa riferimento il brano ha il dubbio se questa parola fosse "auto" oppure "aiuto". Quindi, la parola non era tanto intelligibile.

Comment: Non giurerei che "parola di senso compiuto" sia molto più insolito di "frase di senso compiuto". La prima locuzione, fra virgolette, dà su Google molti risultati relativi all'enigmistica, a linguistica “spicciola”, a test etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cito un esempio di uso dell'espressione "parola di senso compiuto" scritto da Dario Fo che mi sembra perfetto per capire il significato di tale locuzione. Si tratta di un passaggio della storia *Grammelot napoletano di Razzullo* che appare nel libro *Mistero buffo*, pubblicato da Einaudi:

> (*Poi all’istante si rizza in una giravolta improvvisando una danza e canta in grammelot, intercalato con **parole di senso compiuto***) Starrúppia, svilla e fràcca, gli occhi tuoi s’anzícca spurra calore e carrúcca lacrime gioiose spretúcca.

Come potete vedere, questo canto consiste in parole che non hanno nessun senso, come "starrúppia", "svilla" o "fràcca" (il cosiddetto "grammelot") intercalate con parole che hanno un significato, come "gli", "occhi" e "tuoi", che sono appunto le "parole di senso compiuto".

Nella situazione della domanda, la ragazza venne trovata in stato confusionale e non parlava, pronunciava soltanto lamenti, cioè suoni senza nessun significato. A un certo punto però ha detto una "parola di senso compiuto" ("auto" o "aiuto"), cioè, una parola che aveva un significato.

Answer (score 1):

Le parole hanno tutte senso compiuto, nel caso specifico, immagino che la persona fosse confusa o avesse scarso senso della realtà, per cui l'autore specifica che, ciononostante, lei fosse in grado di esprimersi comprensibilmente. Compiuto in questo caso è da intendersi come "completo, definito, concluso."

Comment: In effetti: precedentemente nel romanzo si spiega che la ragazza, che era stata sequestrata, venne trovata in stato confusionale. Il prossimo commento reproduce il dialogo in cui si parla di questo fatto.

Comment: «Senta, sono sceso per andare nel garage a prendere l’auto e ho trovato per terra, davanti alla saracinesca, una donna completamente nuda e tutta coperta di sangue che si lamentava». «Ha detto come si chiama?». «Ma non parla! Si lamenta soltanto. Credo sia in stato confusionale. Mia moglie l’ha portata in casa».

Answer (score 0):

Una parola si dice che abbia senso compiuto, grammaticalmente parlando, quando ha un significato da sola, ad esempio gatto, porta, etc.

Non sono considerate parole di senso compiuto gli articoli, le congiunzioni e tutte quelle che hanno una funzione rispetto alle altre parole, come riportato [qui](https://it.wikibooks.org/wiki/Grammatica_contestuale/La_frase):

> Vi sono parole che hanno un senso compiuto e altre che servono solo
> per indicare una funzione, ossia i rapporti fra le varie parole (o
> monemi), come dei semplici cartellini segnaletici che suggeriscono al
> lettore un certo modo per interpretare le parole che seguono.
> Prendiamo l'articolo (meglio detto determinante grammaticale) il: si
> tratta di una parola senza un senso preciso, serve solo ad indicare e
> determinare la parola che segue. Quando dico il giardino, la parola il
> serve per farci intendere che il giardino da essa indicato non è un
> qualunque giardino, ma uno certo, determinato, distinto da altri; è
> infatti diverso dire il giardino del sultano da ho visto un bel
> giardino.

Quando ad esempio si gioca con gli anagrammi, lo scopo è proprio quello di trovare parole di senso compiuto utilizzando le singole lettere di una parola di partenza:

**Parto** --> **Porta** --> **Prato**

oppure in altri giochi simili lo scopo è quello di ottenere il maggior numero di parole partendo da un insieme di lettere alla rinfusa.

Ritornando al passaggio da te indicato credo che il significato da attribuire sia quello per cui la persona, nonostante la propria condizione, ha detto una parola che ha un qualche significato comprensibile e ben definito.

Comment: Mi sembra che tu stia mettendo insieme due sensi diversi della locuzione “di senso compiuto”. Non c'è nulla che impedisca di usare una preposizione o un articolo in gioco enigmistico come l'anagramma: quello che invece non si potrebbe usare sarebbe, per esempio, “tarop” come anagramma di “prato”. Ed è in questo senso, non in quello grammaticale, che lo usa il personaggio di Camilleri: dice cioè all'interlocutrice che non ha emesso suoni a caso, bensì ha formato una parola ben definita.

Comment: Comunque la terminologia usuale distingue fra parole *lessicali* (“papero”, “saltare”) e quelle “funzionali” o “grammaticali” (“il”, “senza”).

Comment: @DaG Grazie, osservazione corretta. Ho specificato nella risposta.

Comment: @DaG: Penso che abbi ragione nel dire che la spiegazione di abarisone è confusa perché mette insieme due sensi diversi della locuzione “di senso compiuto” come se fossero la stessa cosa (e in questo senso bisognerebbe modificare il post). Tuttavia, a me sembra che il primo significato non sia del tutto privo di senso in questo contesto. (cont.)

Comment: Forse quello che vuol dire il commissario Montalbano è che la parola che ha pronunciato la ragazza è un nome o un verbo, cioè qualche vocabolo che ha un senso da solo, e non qualcosa come un articolo, un preposizione, una conjunzione, ecc che non si potrebbe capire senza un contesto.